# Count the elements in list & array in succession

Tags: arrays, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have list or array or tuple to deal with:

```
A = [1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1]
AA = [a,a,b,b,b,a,b,b,b,b,b,a,a]
```

I want to something like below results:

```
B = [3,-4,3,2]
BB ={a:2, b:3, a:1, b:5, a:2}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `B = [3,-4,3,-2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1]
AA = ['a','a','b','b','b','a','b','b','b','b','b','a','a']
var = 0
counter = 0
B = []
BB = []
for num, val in enumerate(A):
    if var:
        if var==val:
            count = count + val
        else:
            var = val
            B.append(count)
            count = val
    else:
        var = val
        count = val
    if num == len(A) - 1:
        B.append(count)

var = 0
counter = 0
for num, val in enumerate(AA):
    if var: 
        if var==val:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            BB.append([var, count])
            var = val
            count = 1
    else:
        var = val
        count = 1
    if num == len(AA) - 1:
        BB.append([val, count])
```

I don't use a dictionary for the secound because if you use a dict each time you will save a value for 'a' you will override the value so is better another list or tuple if you wish